# Activity window hides hamburger icon and navigation toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer which switches among fragments and activities. Whenever I move to a activity window, the hamburger icon along with the navigation toolbar gets hidden which is why I cannot get back to my navigation drawer. How to resolve the issue?

This is my navigation code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){


            case R.id.nav_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();

                break;

            case R.id.nav_my_events:

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Settings..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Toast.makeText(this,"You logged out..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
```

[image]